# Passing the results of an API call to the class

Tags: php, class, laravel

I've made my own Wrapper for an API I'm working with, Now I have a class where uses can register and I need to results of that API call in the whole class.

> So I'm wondering if it's possible to have the result object that the
>   API returns as an object to work with and pass to other methods

Here's my code, **I added inline comments to clarify the issue**

```
class RegisterController extends Controller {

    private $company;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // This is not the object I want, It's the class that communicates with the API
        $this->company = new Teamleader\Company;
    }

    public function index($id = null)
    {
        // I'm trying to set the class to the result of the API call ( returns an StdObject )
        $this->company = $this->company->get($id);

        // Still returns the original object, not the result of the API call
        var_dump($this->company);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        // Also returns the original object
        dd($this->company);
    }

}
```

Thank you very much, a confused developer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to overwrite the api wrapper, just set it as some custom response object.

```
namespace Teamleader;

class CompanyResponse {

    protected $data = null;

    public function __construct(\stdClass $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    // Whatever other methods you want to be in the API response
}
```

And then in the `get` method in `Teamleader\Company` you will `return new CompanyResponse($data)`

In the `index` method in `RegisterController`, set the response object as a different class property.  There really isn't much of a reason to overwrite the API wrapper you created.

```
$this->companyResponse = $this->company->get($id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Is this a good way of handling API calls? Or am I seeing this the wrong way, I feel like there should be a better way..

Comment: If you have to manipulate/store/cache the data returned by the API, then I would say this is a very good way to go about doing that.  The only thing I would do different is have your api wrapper injected into the controller class.

Comment: Do you maybe have a small example of that? thank you for your time!

Comment: Yeah, which version of Laravel are you running?